# Cannot pass parameter into React handler function

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and having trouble passing a parameter to a handler function. My test code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Container(props) {
  return <button onClick={props.clickHandler("A")}>Tap</button>;
}

function App() {

  function clickHandler(char) {
    console.log(char);
  }

  return <Container clickHandler={clickHandler} />
}

export default App;
```

When I tap the button nothing happens, no console log. What am I doing wrong here? I have tried handlers without parameters before and they work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert **Container** to this

```
function Container(props) {
  return <button onClick={() => props.clickHandler("A")}>Tap</button>;
}
```

You need to pass function to **onClick** but you called it, so you are passing return value of **clickHandler** which is **undefined**

Comment: this is the same as my answer but with a button, should work too :)

Comment: Great thanks! Didn't realise that the functions are automatically called. Is there a name for this style of passing a function? Passing an arrow function?

Comment: @Kex its not automatic, you are calling it :D when you add brackets with arguments after function name, it is called :) this part ("A") calls  props.clickHandler, but I used to do this too when I was new to react. If you don't need custom argument , your onclick can look like this onClick={props.clickHandler}

Answer (score 0):

first you have to pass the function to the Container component like this:
lets say your Container component is a div like this:

```
const Container = props => {
      return(
          <div onClick={props.clickHandler} > your container content here </div>
      )
}

export default Container;
```

this should work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **nested arrow function** in your hander.

By nesting arrow function, you can add additional params in any steps of your process.

```
const handled = () => () => () => {}
```

---

Try the demo in-text:

```js
function Container(props) {
  return <button onClick={props.clickHandler("AAA")}>Tap</button>;
}

function App() {
  const clickHandler = value => char => e => {
    console.log(value, char, e.target.innerText);
  };
  return <Container clickHandler={clickHandler(111)} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```